# Whether it is possible by using grep or find command to replace the given string given only first few and last few words

Tags: sed, grep, find

example:

string : "Hello world XX GM, Super."
         where XX can be different number in all the files.

input : Hello world *Super.
 After running grep or find command. (eg..find -type f -exec ex -sc '%s/**Hello world *Super**./
**Hello world 100 GM, Super.**/g' -cx {} ';')

output should be replaced in every file as:"Hello world 100 GM, Super."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` is the right tool for **finding** things (using regular expressions). It is generally not a tool for **editing** lines.

The correct tool for **editing** is `sed`. Under the simplest assumption, that each line may have at most one occurrence of "Hello world" followed by at most one occurrence of "Super", and that the "words" must be complete words (so: "Hello worldwide peace" is not a match, and "Superman" is not a match), you could do this with

```
$ sed -i 's/\bHello world\b.*\bSuper\b/Hello world 100 GM, Super/' files
```

The `-i` flag means "edit in place" (replace the text in the file itself), and `\b` requires a word boundary in the specific location where it appears in the regular expression.

Comment: Thank you so much mathguy. It helps me to replace 100's of file easily.